# Extract current time, date, timezone of an Iphone user

Tags: timezone, timestamp, nsdateformatter

I would like to extract with Xcode the current time of the Iphone in this format : The date formatted YYYY-MM-DD, the time formatted HH:MM:SSSS and the Time Zone +0000, where is this person.

thanks

Regis

Comment: "where is this person" -- do you want the current date & time of the user?  or do you want the user's current location?  or?  You need to be a bit more clear in your question.

Comment: OK, here are more info. I would like to have the position of the user and the current time and date. I have the GPS code which return to me the location of the user and the timestamp but I do not believe that the time zone in this timestamp is fine. Can you guide me to convert the timestamp to a date string and to a time string? thanks Regis